# phpexcel output disappears immediately in IE

Tags: php, phpexcel

I have this page to display content of an xls file in web page. When I open this page in IE, the content appears for a few seconds and then change to page cannot be displayed. But in firefox it is working

```
<?php
include('../phpexcel/Classes/PHPExcel/IOFactory.php');


?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1" />
<title>ESL, KAKRAPAR</title>
<!--style sheet -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/home_style.css" type="text/css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/common.css" type="text/css" />


</head>

<body>

<div id="container"> 
  <div id="header"><div class="header_text">
</div>
</div>
  <div id="navbar"> <?php include('../kaps/leftmenu.php');?></div> 


<div id="body_content">
 <h3 class="title"> Organisation Chart</h3>
 <?php 
 $inputFileType = 'Excel5';
$inputFileName = 'extreme_data.xls';

$objReader = PHPExcel_IOFactory::createReader($inputFileType);
$objPHPExcel = $objReader->load($inputFileName);

$objWriter = PHPExcel_IOFactory::createWriter($objPHPExcel, 'HTML');
$objWriter->save('php://output');
exit();
?>


</div>


  <div id="footer"><?php include('footer.php');?></div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: what's the html output? do you get any errors/warnings in the browser debug console?

Comment: Firefox shows the content of xls file correctly. But in IE the data is displayed first and immediately changes to 'page cannot be displayed'

Comment: open the developer console in your browser and check if any errors are logged. this is most probably a javascript problem, not a php problem.